# Benefits of four momentum over three momentum

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, scattering

I was wondering, what are the benefits of using four momentum over three momentum in special relativistic equations?

The way I understand it, the four momentum can be applied to specific objects e.g particles, which can then be added via lorentz invariance. Whereas in three momentum this isn't the case, you have to consider all components of the system together. In a sense, four momentum gives us the ability to "break down" each individual component of an interaction and only consider its before and after momentum seperately from the rest of the system without having to consider the before and after momentum of all the other components

I was considering this in the context of compton scattering using four momentum instead of three momentum. Where the momentum of the photon squared is $0$ and the momentum of the electron squared is $m^2c^2$.

Answer (score 3):

No, four-momentum can be transferred between components of a system just like three-momentum. And really, four-momentum conservation is just the combination of three-momentum conservation and energy conservation (if a vector is conserved, all of its components are conserved).

The advantage of four-momentum over three-momentum is that the four-momentum transforms in a nice way under Lorentz transformations. In particular, the magnitude the four momentum, $p^2 = (E/c)^2-p_x^2-p_y^2-p_z^2$ is invariant under Lorentz transformations, whereas the energy and magnitude of the three momentum $\vec p ^2 = p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2$ are not separately invariant.

Answer (score 1):

4-momentum is relativistically covariant, 3-momentum is not.

Comment: 3-momentum is certainly not Lorentz covariant but then, the 4-momentum of an object in an inertial frame is not (generally) the 4-momentum of an object in another inertial frame.  Would you consider clarifying the last sentence?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri :"4-momentum of an object in an inertial frame is not (generally) the 4-momentum of an object in another inertial frame" - why do you say that?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: As for clarifying the last sentence:  I meant that 3-momentum in one inertial frame of reference does not determine 3-momentum in another i.f.r. (unless you know the mass). But I agree, the phrase is not good, I will remove it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The total $4$-momentum is conserved in collisions in any frame whereas total 3-momentum is not: specifically, if we have conservation of 3-momentum in one frame, with 3-momentum defined as $\vec p=m\vec v$, and we Lorentz-transform to a different frame using the correct addition of velocity formula, the resulting 3-momentum in the new frame is not, in general, conserved.

The following example illustrates this:

> In units where $c=1$, a particle of mass $m$ is moving along $+x$ with velocity $v_{1x}=+3/4$ and collides with an object at rest of mass $2m$: $v_{2x}=0$.  In this frame the net momentum before and after collision is $3m/4$.  Using conservation of momentum one rapidly finds that, after collision, the first particle moves with velocity $v'_{1x}=-1/4$ while the second moves with velocity $v_{2x}'=/2$, so the net momentum after the collision is indeed $-m/4+2m1/2=3m1/4$.
>   Now boost to second frame, moving with velocity $\beta=3/4$ with respect to the original frame.  Transforming the velocities one obtains
>    \begin{align}
>  V_{1x}&= 0\, ,\qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad  
>  V_{2x}=-3/4\, ,\\
>  V'_{1x}&=\frac{v'_{1x}-\beta}{1-\beta v'_{1x}}=-\frac{16}{19}\, ,\qquad 
>  V'_{2x}=\frac{v'_{2x}-\beta}{1-\beta 2'_{1x}}=-\frac{2}{5}\, .
>  \end{align}
>    One easily verifies that the net momentum before the collision is $-3m/2$, whereas it is $-156m/95$ after, showing that 3-momentum is not conserved under Lorentz transformations.
>   [This example taken from: Thomas A. Moore, *A Travelers's Guide to Spacetime", McGraw-Hill, 1995]

In addition, the length $p^\mu p_\mu$ of the 4-momentum is invariant under Lorentz transformation, whereas of course the length is the 3-momentum is not.

Comment: "whereas total 3-momentum is not". You need to clarify this: in general, 3-momentum is conserved in collisions.

Comment: @Chris yes you're right... I need to fix this...

Comment: @Chris actually I double checked and indeed I am correct: 3-momentum is not conserved under Lorentz.   I provided an example and clarified my post.

Comment: You've shown that 3-momentum (like 4-momentum) is not invariant in Lorentz transformations- the collision doesn't really have anything to do with it. 3-momentum before and after a collision in an inertial frame is always the same, which is what we mean when we say that 3-momentum is conserved in a collision.

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure I follow.  If 3- momentum is conserved in one frame, it is not conserved in another inertial frame connected by a Lorentz transformation.   4-momentum, on the other hand, is *always* conserved in any two inertial frames (of course the values of the components of the momenta are different, but their sum is nevertheless conserved).  This is *certainly* a benefit of the 4-momentum formulation, as per the question of the OP, who explicitly uses Compton scattering as part of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your example. The issue you have here is that you are using the non-relativistic approximation to 3-momentum ($\vec p=m\vec v$) instead of the correct relativistic version ($\vec p=\gamma m\vec v$). This doesn't have anything to do with the difference between 3-momentum and 4-momentum, it's just the wrong definition of "3-momentum."

Comment: @Chris I'm puzzled.  It seems to me you want to take the last 3 components of the 4-momentum as your definition of the 3-momentum... which is not the usual definition of 3-momentum.  Other than this we agree that what's missing on $\vec p=m\vec v$ is the $\gamma$ factor, which is partly what I undersood the question to be about.

Comment: The last 3 (i.e. the spatial) components of the 4-momentum are the 3-momentum. This can still be written as $\vec p=m\vec v$ if you take $m$ to be the "relativistic mass" $\gamma m_0$. Trying to apply the non-relativistic version to a relativistic problem, however, is just wrong.